# Recording Typhoeus :followlocation with VCR

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

My test suite records a few different types of connections, one through the [bitly gem](https://github.com/philnash/bitly) and the others via [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus).

For some reason, when I use Typhoeus' **:followlocation** option,

```
Typhoeus.get(url, :followlocation => true)
```

the VCR cassette logs the initial url as well as a binary response, which causes subsequent tests run from the cassette to fail.

Previously, I was using Net::HTTP to follow redirects, and each hop was recorded, allowing VCR to properly replay each hop.

How can I get VCR to respond correctly to Typhoeus' response?

[Here's the file](https://github.com/stim371/uncoil/blob/failing-tests/spec/fixtures/uncoil_cassettes/submethod_requests.yml) containing the culprit recording (for the tinyurl link).

The alternative I see is to just not record those requests and require the test suite to hit the real site each time. It's not ideal (or a real solution), but it gets my tests passing.

Comment: Sidenote: Be sure to delete the previous VCR recording.

Comment: After I updated to typhoeus, I blew away all of the cassettes. When you re-run the specs, the first time they are hitting the web and they work (except for the later ones that reuse cassettes recorded earlier in the suite). The next time around they all use the cassettes, and anything that used typhoeus' redirect following does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an open issue about this:

https://github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/293

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just opted out of recording those requests for now, but I'll keep an eye on the issue.